# .Header h1 disappears with margin-top and margin-bottom

Tags: css, templates, themes, blogger, blogspot

I'm making a theme for a blog on Blogger. I want the title of the blog to be in the middle of the header image (which I've aded as a HTML1 gadget, 'cause I didn't want my image to lose quality). I've tried to do this with margins, but every time title of this blog seems to disappear under some transparent space or something. Here's [HTML](http://pasted.co/70680e76) code of a blog. Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Here's the image showing what the problem is.

[image]

A question like this one probably has been already asked, but I would really appreciate some help here. Right now the code of `.Header h1` looks like this:

```css
.Header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999999999999!important;
    font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive;
    color: #92bfb1;
    text-shadow:
           3px 3px 0 #fff,
         -1px -1px 0 #fff,  
          1px -1px 0 #fff,
          -1px 1px 0 #fff,
           1px 1px 0 #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html related to this question?

Comment: Whole html of a blog is pretty long so I can eventually post it on pasted.

Comment: What you should do in cases like that is start removing code until the problem goes away. Then the last thing you removed was the culprit.